# Not able to attach debugger to already running nodejs web app on port 3000

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am not able to attach debugger to the already running NodeJS web app.

Following are my VSCode launching configurations:

```
 "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach",        
        "port": 3001
    },
```

I am getting following error message:

> Cannot connect to runtime process (reason: This socket has been ended by the other party).

Now, when I add `protocol : inspector` in the above configuration, it shows me the following error message:

> Ensure Node was launched with --inspect. Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms

I am currently using v8.6.0 version of NodeJS

Following are my configuration in package.json  >> scripts:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && npm run watch --inspect",
    "build": "npm run build-sass && npm run build-ts && npm run tslint && npm run copy-static-assets",
    "serve": "nodemon dist/server.js",
    "watch": "concurrently -k -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"Sass,TypeScript,Node\" -c \"yellow.bold,cyan.bold,green.bold\" \"npm run watch-sass\" \"npm run watch-ts\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "test": "jest --forceExit",
    "build-ts": "tsc",
    "watch-ts": "tsc -w",
    "build-sass": "node-sass src/public/css/main.scss dist/public/css/main.css",
    "watch-sass": "node-sass -w src/public/css/main.scss dist/public/css/main.css",
    "tslint": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json",
    "copy-static-assets": "node copyStaticAssets.js",
    "debug": "npm run build && npm run watch-debug",
    "serve-debug": "nodemon --inspect dist/server.js",
    "watch-debug": "concurrently -k -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"Sass,TypeScript,Node\" -c \"yellow.bold,cyan.bold,green.bold\" \"npm run watch-sass\" \"npm run watch-ts\" \"npm run serve-debug\""
  },
```

Folder Structure:
[image]

Comment: How are you running the node server?

Comment: simply by using "npm start" command in VS Terminal

Comment: `Ensure Node was launched with --inspect` I think you need to run that with the `--inspect` flag.

Comment: Could you please share the complete command.

Also when try to run the Attach configuration, it giver following error message multiple time:
[Node] GET /json 404 2.859 ms - 143

Comment: `npm start --inspect`? Alternatively, `node bin/www --inspect`

Comment: I have added package.json > scripts section in the question, could you please check if I am doing something wrong there.

Comment: So then you are saying that the `node bin/www --inspect` is not working? Does the error change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156421/discussion-between-harsh-sharma-and-ifconfig).

Comment: Yes, it is not working for me. Error is same as before

Comment: The npm start script should link to node bin/www then the commands should work.

Comment: Nothing worked.

Comment: what does the folder structure look like?

Comment: Please see the attached screenshot in the main question

Answer (score 2):

Made it!

You will have to pass it to the serve **before** specifying the script. In addition, you will need to explicitly specify **the port and the URL** on the script:

```
"serve": "nodemon dist/server.js",
```

Change it to:

```
"serve": "nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 dist/server.js",
```

Apparently vscode works when the URL is `0.0.0.0` and not `127.0.0.1`.

Then, in launch.json:

```
"configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
      "port": 9229,
      "restart": true,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "remoteRoot": "./dist}
]
```

Pay attention to both `localRoot` and `remoteRoot`which I've placed based on the picture you've shown me.